# Yet another thread on The underlying connection was closed. A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server

Tags: c#, rest

I have seen lots of threads on this topic... but solutions on google are not working for me.

I am doing a POST operation using HttpWebRequest object and when I try to post a lot of data I get an error

```
The underlying connection was closed. A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server
```

Now I googled and I found three solutions

1. Set KeepAlive=False and set ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion10.

when I do this, there is no error... but somehow the data which I am posing doesn't reach the server. (so somehow it fails silently... without any error).

If I remove KeepAlive=false and Set ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion10. Then I can see that for small requests everything works fine.... but for large requests I get error of Underlying connection was closed.

1. I also found that some people solved the problem by moving to HttpClient instead of HttpWebRequest... but i think its only for .NET 4.5 but I must compile code for .NET 3.5 at a minimum.
2. Some people solved the problem by

   ServicePoint sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(request.RequestUri);
   sp.Expect100Continue = false;

once again, this threw no errors. but data was no committed.

So for me these solutions are not working.
Do you have any ideas?

Here is my code

```
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(completeUrl);
  request.CookieContainer = Utility.GetSSOCookie(completeUrl);
  request.Method = httpMethod;
  request.Timeout = int.MaxValue;
  Stream reqStream = null;
  string output = null;
  try {
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input) == false) {
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(
                            input
                        );

        request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
        reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
      }
    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse()) {
      using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
        output = reader.ReadToEnd();
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you show code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: By putting the WebResponse in the `using` you're closing the connection right after the first read.  Closing the StreamReader also closes the Stream which probably also closes the connection.

Comment: then why does the code work for small requests and only fail when large amount of data is posted?

Comment: Probably because it doesn't close until all the data is received in the small-data case.  I'd try without the usings to see if that makes a difference.  You can dispose of those two objects in a different way if that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This Exception can be missleading.

I got the same Exception in a scenario where a c# httpclient talks to an asp-mvc (v5) app on iis (v7). After i while it found out that the server runs in a recrusion-loop without throwing a stackoverflow or any log. The result was that the server response the disconection to the client. Maybe this could help someone running into this kind of error.